# Firefox gives British Spellings Despite An American Dictionary

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Ubuntu 101.10
Firefox 9.0.1

Edit > Preferences > Content > Language > Choose  ( reveals the en-us dictionary )

Hi.  I'm running the above browser and OS combination.  When I go to the above menu path I see the dictionary for American English.   However, the spellchecker will mark American spellings as being wrong and British spellings as being correct ( ie favor vs favour,  realization vs realisation ).

I went to the above path, uninstalled the dictionary, reinstalled it and restarted Firefox. The listed dictionary is en-us, but I am still getting a British spellcheck.   Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu user account localized to English-GB?

Comment: iglvzx....how would I determine ( and change ) that?

Comment: I went into System > Admin > Language Support.   Ubuntu is set for American English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, in any multi-line edit window, right click and go Languages > English / United States. That solved the problem for me.  For some reason I don't understand (upgrades?) it gets reset occasionally.

You might also want to ensure you don't have any undesired languages installed: Tools > Add-ons > Languages. Disable or remove any you don't want.

Comment: Thanks Alan, that worked.   I didn't find a "Languages" node after Tools > Add Ons.   I only found US English in Edit > Preferences > Content.  Any idea how I could remove the files for those other versions of English?  Thanks again!

Comment: Find picture included instructions of above, on the sub site for Unix/Linux questions - http://askubuntu.com/questions/50049/how-to-use-american-english-spelling-dictionary-in-firefox